Is the poset in the following construction stationary $\aleph_{\alpha + 2}$-linked?
Definition: A poset P is $\mathbf{stationary}$ $\kappa^{+}$-$\mathbf{linked}$ if for every sequence of conditions $(p_{\gamma} | \gamma < \kappa^{+})$, there is a regerssive function $f: \kappa^{+} \to \kappa^{+}$ (i.e. $f(\gamma) < \gamma$, for $\gamma \neq 0$), such that for some club $C \subseteq \kappa^{+}$ and for all $\gamma, \delta \in C$ with cofinality $\kappa$, $f(\gamma) = f(\delta)$ implies $p_{\gamma}, p_{\delta}$ are compatible.
Construction of the poset: Let V be a model of $SMP_{2}(\omega_{\alpha + 1})$ ($\alpha$ is some fixed countable ordinal). That implies (We do not need the exact definition of SMP, it just gives us the next statements):

$GMA_{\omega_{\alpha + 1}}$ (I will not give definition for $GMA_{\omega_{\alpha + 1}}$, since we do not need it. In fact we need to prove the stationary $\aleph_{\alpha + 2}$-linked in order to use GMA)

$2^{\aleph_{\alpha}} = \aleph_{\alpha + 1}$

$2^{\aleph_{\alpha + 1}}$ is weakly inaccessible


Now let $\aleph_{\alpha + 2} \leq \lambda < 2^{\aleph_{\alpha + 1}}$ and P be the poset consists of conditions of the form $(t, f)$, where

$t$ is a tree of height $\beta + 1$ for some $\beta < \omega_{\alpha + 1}$ and levels at most of size $\aleph_{\alpha}$

$f$ is a function with $dom(f) \subseteq \lambda$, $|dom(f)| = \aleph_{\alpha}$ and $ran(f) = t_{\beta}$, where $t_{\beta}$ is the $\beta$th level of the tree $t$.


The order is defined as follows: $(u, g) \leq (t, f)$ iff

$t$ is an initial segment of $u$, $dom(f) \subseteq dom(g)$,

for every $\delta \in dom(f)$, either $f(\delta) = g(\delta)$ (if $t$ and $u$ have the same height) or $f(\delta) <_{u} g(\delta)$ otherwise.


This is a forcing notion that adds an $\aleph_{\alpha + 1}$-Kurepa tree with $\lambda$ cofinal branches.
I have already proved that it is $< \aleph_{\alpha + 1}$-closed and has the $\aleph_{\alpha + 2}$ chain condition. In order to prove the $\aleph_{\alpha + 2}$ chain condition I noticed that we have only $2^{\aleph_{\alpha}} = \aleph_{\alpha + 1}$-many possibilities for the first coordinate and then applied a $\Delta$-system Lemma on the domains of the second coordinate.
Question: Is P stationary $\aleph_{\alpha + 2}$-linked?
There is a Theorem for the case that $\alpha = 0$, which claims that poset is stationary $\aleph_{2}$-linked, but tells nothing more in the proof. So, I believe the answer is yes, but I cannot see how to prove it

You should define SMP and GMA.

I think it is not necessary. SMP gives us the three statements I have written. This is what we need and the exact definition is complex. As for GMA, we won't use it. In fact we need to prove the stationary $\aleph_{\alpha + 2}$-linked, in order to use GMA.

Pretend for a second that $\lambda = \aleph_{\alpha+2}$.  Is the claim clear?

No, I cannot see why the claim holds if $\lambda = \aleph_{\alpha + 2}$. I would appreciate if you could explain it to me.

Although even if it is true for $\lambda = \aleph_{\alpha + 2}$, it still is not enough. Actually I need to prove it for every $\lambda$ as above.

When you write $2^{\omega_{\alpha+1}}$ in the question, is this still cardinal exponentiation?

Yes, I fixed it.

Basically, the tree part of the forcing has only $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ many possibilities.  Assume $\lambda = \aleph_{\alpha+2}$.  Let your regressive function be $f(p_\alpha) = p \restriction \alpha$.  Since the domains of the second part have size $\leq\aleph_{\alpha}$, this domain is bounded below $\alpha$ when $cf(\alpha) \geq \aleph_{\alpha+1}$.  So if two functions $p_\alpha,p_\beta$ end up having the same lower part, and their upper parts are disjoint, then they are compatible.  For the general case, enumerate the ordinals in question in an $\aleph_{\alpha+2}$-sequence.

I am not sure what you are trying to tell. First of all I do not get why you assume that if some $\gamma$ has cofinality $\aleph_{\alpha + 1}$, the domain is bounded by $\gamma$. There are a lot of elements above $\gamma$ to form a set of size $\aleph_{\alpha}$ (the domains are subsets of $\lambda$, not $\aleph_{\alpha}$. They are just of size $\aleph_{\alpha}$). Furthermore, I am not sure about the function you define. What are the values of the function? Do you mean that the value is the restriction of each function p? The value should be an ordinal.

I mean the part below $\gamma$ is not cofinal in $\gamma$.

I agree with that, but then you tell that if two functions have the same lower part and disjoint upper parts, then they are compatible. I agree but what if they do not have disjoint upper parts? And I am still confused about what are the values of your regressive function. The regressive function should be $f:\omega_{\alpha+2} \to \omega_{\alpha+2}$. You define $f(p_{\gamma}) = p_{\gamma} |{\gamma}$. The domain is fine since there is a map between the functions in the sequence and the ordinals in $\omega{\alpha+2}$, but what is the range? It cannot give a function as a result, but an ordinal

So you take a club $C$ on which for $\alpha<\beta$ from $C$, $\beta$ is above the domain of $p_\alpha$.  This is how you reduce compatibility to the lower parts.  For the actual range, you need to enumerate your tree forcing and relevant subsets like I said.  Sorry I don’t feel like giving more details.  Please look up a proof of the stationary chain condition for Cohen forcing to get an idea.
